# Sharing typescript interfaces between client and server mongoose model

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, typescript, mongoose

I'm trying to share some base interfaces between the client code and the server code. I'm having problems when using the interfaces to create data models in mongoose.

The problem I have is how to access the document._id property in the client. I can't add _id to the User interface without causing compilation errors and I can't access _id without declaring it.

My project layout:

```
/src
-/client
--/user.service.ts
-/server
--/models
---/user.model.ts
-/common
--/common.d.ts
```

user.service.ts

```
import { User } from 'common'

 deleteUser(user: User): Promise<User> {
   return this.http.delete( 'http://someurl/api/users' + user._id )
     .toPromise()
     .then( resp => resp.json().data as User )
     .catch( err => this.errorHandler(err) );
 }
```

user.model.ts

```
import { model, Schema, Document } from 'mongoose';
import { User } from 'common';

let UserSchema = new Schema {
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String,
  email: String
}

export interface UserDocument extends User, Document { }

export var UserModel:Model<UserDocument> = model<UserDocument>('Users', UserSchema);
```

common.d.ts

```
declare module 'common' {
  export interface User {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
  }
}
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can declare `_id` as optional:

```
export interface User {
    _id?: string;
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
    email: string;
}
```

Or you can have another interface for a user with id:

```
export interface PersistedUser extends User {
    _id: string;
}
```

And cast to it whenever needed.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the assistance. I tried optional a while ago, but get `error TS2320: Interface 'UserDocument' cannot simultaneously extend types 'User' and 'Document'.
  Named property '_id' of types 'User' and 'Document' are not identical.` The extended interface will work, was hoping there was a better way, I feel it'll get confusing as the project gets bigger and I need more interfaces for more persisted objects.

Comment: I've implemented the extended interface as suggested, it's working. Thanks

Comment: As of Typescript 2.1, they've added the Partial<T> type for some situations similar to this, too https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html

Comment: @forrestranger `Partial<User>` will make all properties of `User` optional, the OP wanted only the `_id` to be optional.

Comment: Yes I understand.  That's why I said situations similar to this in a comment and not an answer.  It comes up all the time in our code when we're adding types to legacy code and migrating to better APIs.  Thanks for specifying though, it could be confusing to future readers.